# Is there any list of GCC specific hacks for the Linux kernel?

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, compiler-optimization

It seems that there are many GCC-specific hacks (directives/optimisations) for the Linux kernel. I am just wondering, is there an official, consolidated list of them? And is anyone studying or working on them?

Comment: Hacks ?  What does a "hack" mean to you? You mean GCC specific features that the kernel needs to use in order to work ?  Why might someone be working on these hacks?  Currently it works, when it doesn't someone reads GCC documentation and maybe approaches their mailing-list for assistance.  Over time a solution is found.

Comment: "You mean GCC specific features that the kernel needs to use in order to work ?" Yes.                                             Why might someone be working on these hacks?                       To improve them. To Find better option. To understand why we need them and why they work. In embedded system development toolchain development guys generally work on them while dealing with  porting & incompatibilities issues. – Satpal Parmar

Answer (score 1):

See `include/linux/compiler-gcc*.h` for a start.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, see the article
"GCC hacks in the Linux kernel" IBM DveloperWorks:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-gcc-hacks/